# Extracting images from HTML pages with Python

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, extract

The below is my code. It attempts to get the src of an image within an image tag in html.

```
import re
for text in open('site.html'):
  matches = re.findall(r'\ssrc="([^"]+)"', text)
  matches = ' '.join(matches)
print(matches)
```

problem is when i put in something like:

```
<img src="asdfasdf">
```

It works but when i put in an ENTIRE HTML page it returns nothing. Why does it do that? and how do i fix it?

Site.html is just the html code for a website in standard format. I want it to ignore everything and just print the source code for the image. If you would like to see what would be inside site.html then go to a basic HTML webpage and copy all the source code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why use a regular expression to parse HTML when you can **easily** do this with something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> html = """This is some text
... <img src="asdasdasd">
... <i> More HTML <b> foo </b> bar </i>
... """
>>> soup = BS(html)
>>> for imgtag in soup.find_all('img'):
...     print(imgtag['src'])
... 
asdasdasd
```

---

The reason why your code doesn't work is because `text` is one line of the file. Thus, you are only finding matches of a line in every iteration. Although this may work, think about if the last line doesn't have an image tag. `matches` will be an empty list, and `join` will make it become `''`. You are overriding the variable `matches` every line.

You want to call `findall` on the whole HTML:

```
import re
with open('site.html') as html:
    content = html.read()
    matches = re.findall(r'\ssrc="([^"]+)"', content)
    matches = ' '.join(matches)

print(matches)
```

Using a `with` statement here is much more pythonic. It also means you don't have to call `file.close()` afterwards, as the `with` statement deals with that.

Comment: I know but i want to do it with regex not beautiful soup... (I am entering this online and the test does not allow for beautifulsoup)

Comment: @user2655778 Alright then, could you perhaps show us `site.html` (at least bits of it) :)

Comment: @user2655778 Wait, don't worry, I think I found the solution

Comment: @user2655778 oh you want to [parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Haidro Thanks for that but where would i put the above code?

Comment: Never mind i got it @Haidro, just that you forgot to change text to content thanks for the solution!

Comment: @user2655778 You're welcome! I also edited my answer just as you commented :)

Comment: But I have another question,  how then do I extract any specific tags for my business, if I have to, without using `BeautifulSoup` or `re`

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by using beautiful soup and base64 module

```
    import base64
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

    with open('site.html') as html_wr:
        html_data = html_wr.read()

    soup = BS(html_data)
    
    for ind,imagetag in enumerate(soup.findall('img')): 
         image_data_base64 = imagetag['src'].split(',')[1]
         decoded_img_data = base64.b64decode(image_data_base64)
         with open(f'site_{ind}.png','wb+') as img_wr:
             img_wr.write(decode_img_data)

    ##############################################################
    # if you want particular images you can use x-path
    
    import base64
    from lxml import etree
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
    
    with open('site.html') as html_wr:
        html_data = html_wr.read()

    soup = BS(html_data)
    dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
    img_links = dom.xpath('')  #insert the x-path
    
    for ind,imagetag in enumerate(img_links): 
         image_data_base64 = imagetag.values()[3].split(',')[1]
         decoded_img_data = base64.b64decode(image_data_base64)
         with open(f'site_{ind}.png','wb+') as img_wr:
             img_wr.write(decode_img_data)
```